# axon 4 snapshot in demand

Tags: spring-boot, snapshot, axon

I work with spring boot and axon example, i implement the snapshot feature, with the below code is working fine, after 3 events i found the data in the table snapshot_event_entry in the database

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(value = { AxonAutoConfiguration.class })
public class AxonConfig {

    @Bean
    public SnapshotTriggerDefinition catalogSnapshotTrigger(Snapshotter snapshotter) {
        return new EventCountSnapshotTriggerDefinition(snapshotter, 3);
    }
}


@Aggregate(snapshotTriggerDefinition = "catalogSnapshotTrigger")
public class CatalogAggregate { }
```

My question, is there a method to do a snapshot in demand? That means i want to implement an api to do the snapshot, not automatically after 3 events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is nothing already in place.
One way to implement what you need is to create a dedicated Command, eg `PerformShapshotCmd`, that will carry the aggregateId information, and a `@CommandHandler` into your Aggregate. You could then let Spring autowire the Snapshotter instance bean, and call for the `scheduleSnapshot(Class<?> aggregateType, String aggregateIdentifier)` method.

Below some code snippet that could guide you.

```
data class PerformShapshotCmd(@TargetAggregateIdentifier val id: String)
```

```
    @CommandHandler
    public void handle(PerformShapshotCmd cmd, Snapshotter snapshotter) {
        logger.debug("handling {}", cmd);

        snapshotter.scheduleSnapshot(this.getClass(), cmd.getId());
    }
```

You should also define one Bean of type Snapshotter into your config

```
@Bean
public SpringAggregateSnapshotterFactoryBean snapshotter() {
    SpringAggregateSnapshotterFactoryBean springAggregateSnapshotterFactoryBean = new SpringAggregateSnapshotterFactoryBean();
    //Setting async executors
    springAggregateSnapshotterFactoryBean.setExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
    return springAggregateSnapshotterFactoryBean;
}
```

Please note that the first argument of your commandHandler needs to be the command, otherwise the framework will complain with an exception at startup time.

Comment: thnx for your answer. i added a method in my aggregate as you indicated, but I did not find anything in the table `snapshot_event_entry`

Comment: https://github.com/akanzari/sample-axon-kafka/blob/master/axon-producer/src/main/java/com/axonkafka/aggregate/CatalogAggregate.java

Comment: from your code sample I can't see any Bean of Snapshotter defined. Add one to your AxonConfig. I edited my reply with one code snippet sample.

Please also have a look at this thread for further information 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63767707/implementing-axon-snapshot-with-springboot-2-3-3-and-axon-4-4-2